# Multiple zombie process of epmd daemon in docker RabbitMQ container causes unhealthy healthcheck

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang, epmd

i have a probleme with RabbitMQ and EPMD Daemon, i'm using RabbitMQ 3.10.11 in docker on system os Fedora Core OS. Since my last udpade of system 37.20230110.3.1 i noticed that my docker healthcheck is unhealthy after two days running normaly.

After my research i seen that i have several epmd daemon process running into container, every minute i've new daemon of epmd process who run. My healthcheck docker return unhealthy when the new epmd process can't start.

Finaly i've 1900 epmd process running and my healthcheck unhealthy

My docker cmd healthcheck is "rabbitmq-diagnostics -q status"

However rabbitMQ works fine

Has anyone ever encountered a problem like this or have a solution for me?

Comment: You are probably running into this issue - https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/7160, https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/discussions/7160#discussioncomment-4853841. Unfortunately Team RabbitMQ is unable to reproduce this issue, so if you have instructions how, please provide them in that discussion.